# R difficulty recognizing regex expressions with [:...:]

Tags: r, regex, string, replace

I have:

```
testA <- tibble(a = "XYZ spqr MN 123456 MN8Ab1234", b = 1)

fixcontents <- function(mydf, mypattern1, mypattern2, mycol) {
  mydf[[mycol]] <- gsub(mypattern1, mypattern2, mydf[[mycol]])
  return(mydf)
}

testB <- testA
# testB <- fixcontents(testA, "([:alpha:]{3})\\s", "AAA", 1) # replacement does not work
# testB <- fixcontents(testA, "([A-Z]{3})\\s", "AAA ", 1)    # replacement works
# testB <- fixcontents(testA, "([:digit:]{6})", "000000", 1) # replacement does not work
# testB <- fixcontents(testA, "(\\d{6})", "000000", 1)       # replacement works
# testB <- fixcontents(testA, "(11\\w{4})", "000000", 1)     # replacement works
testB
```

The expected replacements are 
 XYZ spqr MN 123456 MN8Ab1234 -> XYZ spqr MN 000000 MN8Ab1234
 and 
 XYZ spqr MN 123456 MN8Ab1234  -> AAA spqr MN 123456 MN8Ab1234

Why is R not recognizing [:alpha:] and [:digit:]?

Comment: What is your expected output   `[[:alpha:]]` and `[[:digit:]]`

Comment: It is a known thing, use `[[:classname:]]`